# How to do deep test of arg of the function in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function in Jest which receives 2 arguments. First argument is array containing big objects. I need to test many things regarding that first argument.

For example array contains 2 types of objects:

```
{
      "BlockType": "QUERY_RESULT",
      "ColumnIndex": null,
      "ColumnSpan": null,
      "Confidence": 97,
      "EntityTypes": null,
      "Geometry": {
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Height": 0.0780341774225235,
          "Left": 0.3675669729709625,
          "Top": 0.34067028760910034,
          "Width": 0.6192638874053955,
        },
        "Polygon": [
          {
            "X": 0.3675934970378876,
            "Y": 0.34067028760910034,
          },
          {
            "X": 0.9868237376213074,
            "Y": 0.3410104811191559,
          },
          {
            "X": 0.9868308305740356,
            "Y": 0.41870445013046265,
          },
          {
            "X": 0.3675669729709625,
            "Y": 0.4183456003665924,
          },
        ],
      },
      "Hint": null,
      "Id": "69b5b7e6-b8f9-4c03-9c18-d5ca72a3b142",
      "Page": 1,
      "PageClassification": null,
      "Query": null,
      "Relationships": null,
      "RowIndex": null,
      "RowSpan": null,
      "SearchKey": "Sample title",
      "SelectionStatus": null,
      "Text": "Sample title",
      "TextType": null,
    },
    {
      "BlockType": "QUERY",
      "ColumnIndex": null,
      "ColumnSpan": null,
      "Confidence": null,
      "EntityTypes": null,
      "Geometry": null,
      "Hint": null,
      "Id": "b67ca6b2-a53c-4a2c-9960-0dca93561804",
      "Page": 1,
      "PageClassification": null,
      "Query": {
        "Alias": null,
        "Pages": null,
        "Text": "What is the page title?",
      },
      "Relationships": [
        {
          "Ids": [
            "69b5b7e6-b8f9-4c03-9c18-d5ca72a3b142",
          ],
          "Type": "ANSWER",
        },
      ],
      "RowIndex": null,
      "RowSpan": null,
      "SelectionStatus": null,
      "Text": null,
      "TextType": null,
    },
```

I have a test case which simulate change event on textbox and as a result test function gets called.

```
  it("test argument", async () => {

      const textareas = Array.from(screen.getAllByTestId((id) => id === 'answer-text-area'));

      await waitFor(() => {
        const value = textareas[0].childNodes[0].value
        expect(value).not.toBeNull();
        fireEvent.change(textareas[0].childNodes[0], {target: {value: `${value} 23`}})
        expect(textareas[0].childNodes[0].value).toBe(`${value} 23`)
      });
      await wait(2000);
      
      expect(annotationUtils.convertResponseObjectToFile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
        "Blocks": expect.any(Array),
          "DocumentMetadata": {
            "Pages": 1,
          },
      }), "annotation_unit_pdf.json");




    });
```

I need to verify below things:

1. How many objects has property BlockType with value QUERY
2. Need to validate number of IDS in relationship array and validate corresponding geometry

I read Jest documentation and also looks everywhere online, couldn't find anything that can help with this.

Comment: Did you read https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#using-a-mock-function? That shows how to access the call args, then you can assert on them however you like.